# Is it possible to "apply fadein fadeout effect in multiple merged audios" in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have working on one project of its requirement, i want to apply fadein fadeout effect in multiple merged audio. So please guide me and suggest me that is it possible or not. And if it is possible give me the best solution.